# Azure webjob max execution time or Blob queue max lock retry

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-blob-storage

In my project i have Webjob which is triggered by queue. Its sending newsletter and its time consuming i can say exactly how long it takes but more than 10 minutes.

Logic to update release lock every 25 seconds

```
queue.UpdateMessage(data, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0), MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
```

Everything works as expected till today when it just failed with message **Never Finished 57 minutes ago** and i see that same message was queued 3 times.

I've added logging to see why, but it will take probably few days till next newsletter. So maybe somebody know about recent changes or limits?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure webjob max execution time

As far as I know, azure web job doesn't have the max execution time.

Here is a test, the webjob execute 30 minutes.

[image]

> Blob queue max lock retry

I couldn't understand why you  release lock of the queue message which the web job method currently used.

If a web job is triggered by one queue message, it will be invisible until the method fail or complete.

Azure web job SDK will call a function up to 5 times to process a queue message. If the fifth try fails, the message is moved to a poison queue.

The poison queue name is {originalqueuename}-poison.

About how to set the maximum number of retries, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues#config).

---

Update:

[image]

Comment: Its not true about queue. After you dtart processing it will be invisible only 60 secs

Comment: As far as I know, the SDK will keep the queue message invisible. See my update image.

Comment: Sorry mate but have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted maybe you have have something custom